# The same OOM curve on different apps

Tags: google-fabric

We recorded our crashes and OOM on the Fabric, but recently discovered that several of our apps on different servers have the same OOM anomaly curve at the same time. I would like to know if anyone understands this situation. Or if someone has the same situation as me.

[image: Abnormal 1]
[image: Abnormal 2]
[image: Abnormal 3]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in may, particularly on may 9th, 15th and 18th.
Does that match yours?

Cordially,

Comment: My situation is more frequent here